# Calculating the working hours in a given period

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to create a function where I can calculate the total working hours in a given period.

Explanation:
inputs are in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format.

For example user Inputs:
startDateTime: 01/10/2013 9:30am endDateTime: 12/12/2013 5pm

Daily working hours from 7am to 5pm. For example, if someone starts working at 9am and ends at 8pm them is working hours will calculate as 8 hours (only calculate the working hours between 7am to 5pm).

I do have a holiday list:

Every week's Saturday and Sunday are holiday
and bellow are the public holidays

HOLIDAY LIST:

07/04/yyyy
12/25/yyyy
12/31/yyyy

Memorial Day:- Last Monday of every May

Labor Day:- First Monday of Every September

Thanksgiving Day:- Fourth Thursday of every November

Now my problem is how to find out Memorial Day, Labor Day and Thanksgiving Day with in any given time period.
Final output will be the total working hours in the given period substituting the hours of holiday.

Bellow function I'm using only to calculate working hours eliminating weekends

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkTime] 
(
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @FinishDate DATETIME
)

RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp BIGINT
    SET @Temp=0

DECLARE @FirstDay DATE
SET @FirstDay = CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate, 112)

DECLARE @LastDay DATE
SET @LastDay = CONVERT(DATE, @FinishDate, 112)

DECLARE @StartTime TIME
SET @StartTime = CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate)

DECLARE @FinishTime TIME
SET @FinishTime = CONVERT(TIME, @FinishDate)

DECLARE @WorkStart TIME
SET @WorkStart = '07:00'

DECLARE @WorkFinish TIME
SET @WorkFinish = '17:00'

DECLARE @DailyWorkTime BIGINT
SET @DailyWorkTime = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @WorkStart, @WorkFinish)

IF (@StartTime<@WorkStart)
BEGIN
    SET @StartTime = @WorkStart
END
IF (@FinishTime>@WorkFinish)
BEGIN
    SET @FinishTime=@WorkFinish
END

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE
SET @CurrentDate = @FirstDay
DECLARE @LastDate DATE
SET @LastDate = @LastDay

WHILE(@CurrentDate<=@LastDate)
BEGIN       
    IF (DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=1 AND DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)!=7)
    BEGIN
        IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
        BEGIN
            SET @Temp = @Temp + @DailyWorkTime
        END
        --IF it starts at startdate and it finishes not this date find diff between work finish and start as minutes
        ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate!=@LastDay)
        BEGIN
            SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(HOUR, @StartTime, @WorkFinish)
        END

        ELSE IF (@CurrentDate!=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
        BEGIN
            SET @Temp = @Temp + DATEDIFF(HOUR, @WorkStart, @FinishTime)
        END
        --IF it starts and finishes in the same date
        ELSE IF (@CurrentDate=@FirstDay) AND (@CurrentDate=@LastDay)
        BEGIN
            SET @Temp = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @StartTime, @FinishTime)
        END
    END
    SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @CurrentDate)
END

-- Return the result of the function
IF @Temp<0
BEGIN
    SET @Temp=0
END
RETURN @Temp

END
```

Please help me how to find out the Thanksgiving Day, Labor Day and Memorial Day in a given period.

Comment: Maybe you could check this one first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201643/labor-day-vs-thanksgiving

Comment: I think you would have killed your workers long before the difference in hours between their start and end time would be a bigint

Comment: You need a calendar table which contains every date in the range of interest, and the working hours on that day.

Comment: @Ben But inputs could be anything any range (working hours are fixed). You mean, do I need to maintain a calendar table by presuming a possible date range.

Comment: @rahulchrty, Any range? You have to manage people working during the Middle Ages?

Comment: @Ben no indeed, but its still like 24 years